# resize google maps not working and takes long time

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, resize, directions

At first, my problem was that the google maps with direction service was not loading correctly. After some researches, i find `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize').` Ok, now it works. Kinda.

The order of my app is: page x, page A with the map and the direction, page y, page B with the map and the direction.

My script is:

```
function initialize(mapa_id) {
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        draggable: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.583693,-48.042186),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapa_id), mapOptions);
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');         
          directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
          if(mapa_id == 'map-canvas'){
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(rotaInicial, onError, options);
          }else{
              directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(rotaFinal, onError, options);  
          }
    }

function rotaInicial(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.578659,-48.038045);

      var request = {
          origin:start,
          destination:end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
      });
    }

function rotaFinal() {
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.578659,-48.038045);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.585503,-48.038324);

    var request = {
          origin:start,
          destination:end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
      });
    }
```

So, what happens  now: the page A loads the map first (correctly and with no directions) and then after a few seconds (5 - 8) the 'resize' happens and it shows the directions. Then it goes to page y, after click the button it goes to the page B and the map appears only on the top left. After a few seconds again, the 'resize' happens and show the directions. when i do this routine again (back to page x), the first map loads also in top left and it happens all those things.

I have two problems.

1. When the page loads, i want to show the map already with directions.
2. If is not possible ok, but at least it should load the map correctly. And this resize should work faster.

I'm not sure if i put the 'resize' code in the right place. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you call both functions that will draw the route(rotaInicial & rotaIFinal) in the success-callback of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`  . `getCurrentPosition` will be executed asynchronously and it may take some time till you get a result.

Therefore, as long as you need to set the direction based on the users location, there isn't anything you can do to speed-up the drawing of the directions.

Comment: :/ hmm, i get it... thats ok then. Now i have just one problem left! thank you.